# 1 Resource File vs Many

Tags: c#, globalization, resource-files

I have a site that I am manually adding Spanish and Portuguese support to via resource files and GetGlobalResourceObject() in my pages.

I have several types of users that have essentially their own sections of the site. I currently only have one big Language.resx file (for each language) that holds all the "translations".

My Question:

**Would having one big resource file for the entire site be a performance bottle neck vs having 1 resource file per page/form?**

The files contain about 800 lines of text. I am currently using excel to generate the resource files (xml) via concatenate(), which makes it easy for me to update the .resx files at this point.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reasons for having multiple resource files are:

- Organizational - it is easier to organize and find the resources for each language
- Deployment - changes to any single language translations can be deployed independently

Performance wise - having a single file would, under normal circumstances cause less IO than having the same information across multiple files. However, since this is a cost that is only incurred once (when reading the resource files), it would normally be negligible.

Comment: So are resource files only loaded once (upon first time access), then only loaded again after a file update or server restart?

Comment: @ToddBFisher - As far as I know.